# C# compile Unknown MSBuild error MonoDevelop Linux

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, mono

i just started to learn c# on my linux and i'm using monodevelop ide, i got this error while compile c# file *"Unknown MSBuild error"*.

here my code :

```
using System;

namespace Application
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
        public static void Main(){
            Console.WriteLine ("aaaaaa");
        }
    }
}
```

and here my last log :

```
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Starting MonoDevelop 5.10.1
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Running on Mono 4.4.0 (Stable 4.4.0.40/f8474c4 Mon Mar 28 12:22:29 UTC 2016) (64-bit)
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Operating System: Linux
Linux ardi 4.5.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 7 20:43:57 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.30
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Ide
WARNING [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: No proxy credential provider was found
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Initializing Runtime Mono 4.4.0
Starting MonoDevelop
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GnomePlatform
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VBBinding
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.TextTemplating
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xml
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNet
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Refactoring
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl
WARNING [2016-05-11 22:06:07Z]: Inotify watch limit is too low (8192).
MonoDevelop will switch to managed file watching.
See http://monodevelop.com/Inotify_Watches_Limit for more info.
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PackageManagement
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GtkCore
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Deployment
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WebReferences
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.NUnit
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CBinding
   Memuat Workbench
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DocFood
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git
      Initializing Jendela Utama
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:08Z]: Creating DefaultWorkbench
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:09Z]: Updating Welcome Page from 'http://software.xamarin.com/Service/News'.
WARNING [2016-05-11 22:06:09Z]: Welcome Page news server could not be reached.
ERROR [2016-05-11 22:06:09Z]: Monodoc documentation tree could not be loaded.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/usr/lib/monodoc/monodoc.xml".
File name: '/usr/lib/monodoc/monodoc.xml'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) <0x7fd08b93f270 + 0x005ca> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) <0x7fd08b93ef30 + 0x0004d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int)
  at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream (System.Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) <0x412d1900 + 0x0009e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity (System.Uri absoluteUri, System.String role, System.Type ofObjectToReturn) <0x412d1720 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate (System.Object xmlResolver) <0x41379960 + 0x00060> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl () <0x41379670 + 0x00127> in <filename unknown>:0 
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:09Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:09Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:12Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ILAsmBinding
INFO [2016-05-11 22:06:13Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.HexEditor
ERROR [2016-05-11 22:06:19Z]: RunTarget failed
System.Exception: MSBuild operation failed

Server stack trace: 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.BuildEngine.RunSTA (System.Threading.ThreadStart ts) <0x41a5c2e0 + 0x003cf> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectBuilder.Run (MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectConfigurationInfo[] configurations, ILogWriter logWriter, MSBuildVerbosity verbosity, System.String[] runTargets, System.String[] evaluateItems, System.String[] evaluateProperties, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 globalProperties) <0x41a5e3a0 + 0x002b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices:InternalExecute (System.Reflection.MethodBase,object,object[],object[]&)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.InternalExecuteMessage (System.MarshalByRefObject target, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg) <0x7f5c2b163e20 + 0x0026c> in <filename unknown>:0 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
 ---> System.ArgumentException: path string must not be an empty string or whitespace string
  at System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory (System.String path) <0x7f5c2b0ce110 + 0x00085> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Environment.set_CurrentDirectory (System.String value) <0x7f5c2b0bc300 + 0x0000c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectBuilder.SetupProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectConfigurationInfo[] configurations) <0x41a60430 + 0x001cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectBuilder+<Run>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () <0x41a5e830 + 0x000c3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.BuildEngine.STARunner () <0x41a5c8c0 + 0x00084> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_remoting_wrapper (intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke) MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectBuilder:Run (MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectConfigurationInfo[],MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ILogWriter,MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildVerbosity,string[],string[],string[],System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string>)
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.RemoteProjectBuilder.Run (MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.ProjectConfigurationInfo[] configurations, ILogWriter logWriter, MSBuildVerbosity verbosity, System.String[] runTargets, System.String[] evaluateItems, System.String[] evaluateProperties, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 globalProperties) <0x416f08d0 + 0x00082> in <filename unknown>:0
```

my monodevelop version : 5.10.1

my mono version : 4.4.0

OS : Arch Linux 64bit with latest kernel update

Comment: I experience this error sometimes. Just restart mono and try to compile again.