# MonoDevelop Error: Unknown MSBuild failure. Please try building the project again

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, mono

Just installed MonoDevelop and I tried to compile a simple "Hello World".
Code I used:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

The error that I get is :

```
EmptyCSharpFile.csproj(1,1): Error: Unknown MSBuild failure. Please try building the project again (EmptyCSharpFile)
```

[image: Error Message]

My system info:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , updated
The MonoDevelop and mono are freshly installed.
Mono JIT compiler version 5.0.1.1
MonoDevelop Version 5.10
I can use mcs and run it but can't use monodevelop to run it.
I did read these similar topics but no response yet:
[MonoDevelop Failure "Unknown MSBuild Failure" on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980702/monodevelop-failure-unknown-msbuild-failure-on-linux) ;
[C# compile Unknown MSBuild error MonoDevelop Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178514/c-sharp-compile-unknown-msbuild-error-monodevelop-linux) ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/73630/could-not-obtain-c-compiler-error-when-using-monodevelop

Comment: Mono 5.x are latest, while MonoDevelop 5.x are too old. Please try to compile the project at terminal via msbuild command and see what exactly happens.

Comment: The problem is that you need to create a C# project, called a "Solution". Unlike with C++, individual `.cs` files can't be compiled and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had the same problem when I first installed it , I assume you went straight to **file -> new-> file-> general -> emptyc# file.**

Instead of that, go to **file->new-> solution**  from there choose **Console C# project** or simply press ctrl + shift + N choose next ,and give project name, by default the new project has  a simple hello world program run it, this time it will work.(it worked for me)

Comment: How can I fix an existing project that has this error?

Comment: I have no idea, I just did a simple hello world and uninstalled it.